# How do I draw/paint lines on top of a Bitmap using EaselJS?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I'm trying to use the [sample from the createJS/easelJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos/drawing) site where it sets up a createjs.Shape() and adds it as a child to the `createjs.stage()`.

Then using the mousedown/mousemove/mouseup handlers, the stage is updated using the graphics methods - `setStrokeStyle`, `beginStroke`, and `curveTo`.

The main difference is that I'm also adding a `new Bitmap(url)` and also adding it as a child to my stage (before adding the `createjs.Shape` for drawing).

However, when I test it, I can only "draw" on the areas not occupied by the Bitmap. How can I get this to work, so I can draw/paint on top of the Bitmap?

The end goal is a coloring page - being able to add different black&white images and have multiple color brushes to color it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it working by creating the `new createjs.Bitmap` object from an Image object instead of passing the url of the image to the Bitmap's constructor. Then adding both my drawingCanvas's `createjs.Shape` object and Bitmap's object to the loaded event handler. So this works:

```
var image, stage, drawingCanvas, bitmap;
function init(){
 image = new Image();
 image.onload = handleImgLoad();
 image.src = 'image-source-url.png';
 stage = new createjs.Stage("testCanvas");
 createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
 drawingCanvas = new createjs.Shape();
}

function handleImgLoad(){
 bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
 stage.addChild(bitmap, drawingCanvas);

 ... code to handle mouseup/down/move events...
}
```